# Special characters not carrying over correctly in project names in Excel report

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I am trying to download Project Name, I'm getting a different character for special charter in the Excel export.

What should I do so all my special characters are correctly shown?

```
protected void lnkExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //INS1-219
        DataTable dt1 = DataHelper.ExecuteQuery(Session["strForExcelReport"].ToString());
        DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
        dt3.Columns.Add("Project Code");
        dt3.Columns.Add("Project Name");
        /// many more columns

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt1.Rows)
        {
            drnew["Project Code"] = dr["ProjectCode"].ToString();
            drnew["Project Name"] = dr["ProjectName"].ToString();
            drnew["Client"] = dr["OrganizationName"].ToString();              
            // many, many business rules 
            dt3.Rows.Add(drnew);
        }
        // DataTable is now complete
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=ProjectInHandDetailsList_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy") + ".xls";
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        string tab = "";
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt3.Columns)
        {
            Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
            tab = "\t";
        }
        Response.Write("\n");
        int i;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt3.Rows)
        {
            tab = "";
            for (i = 0; i < dt3.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());
                tab = "\t";
            }
            Response.Write("\n");
        }

        Response.End();
        //END INS1-219
    }
```

With above code a projectname comes out in the Excel sheet like this:

> Royal Free Flash Case Study 3â€“Pleuritic Chest Pa

while this is the value from the database:

> Royal Free Flash Case Study 3 – Pleuritic Chest Pa

How do I prevent those strange characters from showing up?

Comment: I've edited (literally removed most of the code) your question what I think now resembles a bit of an [MCVE]. Please check my [edit] and enhance it when needed. You might also want to use the [checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to verify if your question is ready to be posted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an [Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8(v=vs.110).aspx), both in the [ContentEncoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contentencoding(v=vs.110).aspx) header and a [StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) to write the strings to the OutputStream. Encoding mismatches are the reason for the strange replacement of characters.

```
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    // set the contentencoding of the http content
    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    // use a streamwriter that knows how to write strings in 
    // a specified encoding to a stream
    using(var sw = new StreamWriter(Response.OutputStream, Response.ContentEncoding))
    {
        string tab = "";
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt3.Columns)
        {
            // use the StreamWriter
            sw.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
            tab = "\t";
        }
        sw.Write("\n");
        int i;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt3.Rows)
        {
            tab = "";
            for (i = 0; i < dt3.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                sw.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());
                tab = "\t";
            }
            sw.Write("\n");
        }
    }
    Response.End();
```